# How to use bios routine 10h 13h?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I'm trying to use the bios routine [`10h 13h`](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_023.20.html) to print a string, but it requires registers `ES` and `BP` to be set. I'm fairly new to assembly and don't know how to use them properly yet, I read a bit online and found out these are stack pointers (not *entirely* sure on that?).

I have another suspicion, and it is that I may be not using the right interrupt, and if that's also the case, then please tell me.

This is my code as of right now.

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov ah, 13h ;thing
    mov al, 00h ;subservice 
    mov bh, 00h ;display page (what is this??)
    mov bl, 00h ;attrributes (what is this??)
    mov cx, len ;length of string
    mov dh, 1ah ;row
    mov dl, 1ah ;column 
    ;todo: somehow make a pointer to the string??
    mov es,    ;set this
    mov bp,    ;set this

    int 0x10
    
    ;padding and magic number
    jmp $
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    db 0x55, 0xAA
section .data
    text db "Hello, World.", 0x0a
    len equ $ - text
```

Comment: `ES:BP` must be set to the address of the string.  `ES` to the segment, `BP` to the offset.  I strongly recommend you to start with something easier if you are confused about segmentation.  Also, consider writing DOS programs before moving to writing your own boot loader.  They have less constraints to deal with.

Comment: Your data is after the boot signature, outside the 512 bytes that get loaded.  Also it's in a different section, but flat binaries don't have sections.   Any particular reason you want to learn obsolete 16-bit BIOS stuff?  You tagged this x86-64; the only thing x86-64 about this is that modern CPUs call this "legacy mode", booting code that's unaware of x86-64 and never switches to long mode.  Writing 32-bit code under GNU/Linux (or whatever mainstream OS you're most familiar with) is probably easier to learn and more directly able to translate to modern 64-bit code.  (flat memory model)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hi, yes, I'm currently learning os dev with a friend, i know most the basics, just struggling a bit with doing memory related stuff currently. I'm using windows to develop, nasm to convert assembly files to binaries and qemu to run them. Also i figured the data would get loaded after the boot sector, and confirmed that for my self after looking at the binary file nasm made :/.  I'm running out of comment characters, so let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: @Sect0r It doesn't matter how long your file is, the BIOS will only load one sector (512 byte) of data on boot.  If you need data after that sector, you have to manually load it into memory.  For this reason among other things, I recommend avoiding the whole boot sector stuff until you are more experienced.

Comment: @fuz I'm doing it for fun, and also cause im bored :P. I'm currently trying to allocate some extra data and then store the string and its length, that way they can be addressable, i think.

Comment: @Sect0r All memory is addressable.  I am not sure what you think you need to do.

Comment: @fuz You said bios only loads the boot sector, right?

Comment: @Sect0r Yes.  So you need to put the string into the boot sector or load it from disk later on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228760/discussion-between-sect0r-and-fuz).

Comment: Think about how the system actually boots (in legacy BIOS mode, not modern UEFI): it loads 512 bytes from the start of the disk into memory, and then jumps to it at CS:IP=`0000:7c00` (or `007c0:0000`).  If your data isn't in that first 512 bytes, it doesn't get loaded.  The whole disk is larger, but the term "boot sector" is not an accident: there's no metadata to tell it how much to load, so it's a fixed 512 bytes.  That's *why* you're using `times 510-($-$$)` bytes of padding, to reach 2 bytes before the end of that 512.